# Hyper Light Drifter: How do I get past these barriers?

Tags: hyper-light-drifter

So, I've been trying to get through this game, and I've completed various sections but no full areas yet, mainly because of this issue: I keep coming across these barriers, but I seem to have no way to get past them.

I'm not sure if the game explained how to get past it in a previous section, or if there's something that I'm completely missing. Either way, I'm pretty much stuck until I can figure this out.

Any help, whether a nudge or a full explanation would be helpful.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the Arrow marking on each of those blocks, the game has not hinted at a way to remove them. You've definitely missed something in each of the three areas you can currently go to (you cannot go to the South yet, as your screenshot shows).

The way to remove the blocks is to interact with the large diamond-shaped objects that each boss of the game guards, each with a corresponding arrow on it. In order to get past the blocks pictured in your screenshot, you'll need to clear all three of the other areas.

Though you may appear to be blocked, you're certainly missing modules you can reach (that is, those diamond-shaped things). Speaking to the other drifter in each area only marks half of the area's modules on your map, so if you can't figure out how to get one you may try looking elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! Honestly, I thought maybe the arrows had to do with light dashing.